# NServiceBus publishing in a multi system environment

Tags: nservicebus

I work on a system where we have the same website across multiple countries. Each of these websites has it's own services. Everything works well, but I've always found myself having to send messages rather than publishing as the messages otherwise other services where I know before hand it's completely irrelevant. It sounds pointless to me publishing to many services and then filtering it's relevance.

Is there a practice I should be dealing with when wanting to publish messages to a certain subset of services, how have others dealt with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default endpoints subscribe to all messages. If you want only certain endpoints to subscribe to specific sets, then you need to configure your endpoint to DoNotAutoSubscribe().  You then must explicitly subscribe to each message type the endpoint will be interested in using Bus.Subscribe().

Answer (score 0):

Could you describe your logic of determining relevance for particular endpoint systems ? the purpose of publishing and subscribing is that there are events in a system that other endpoints can subscribe to.
you should not know something about your subscribers. so how do you determine relevance ?

if these messages are not relevant for a specific endpoint why do you want to subscribe to these messages ?

Answer (score 0):

If it truly is an event message then you need to publish the message.  If you need to publish to a subset you could have a separate subscription store that the endpoint in question would use.

Typically it should be up to the subscriber to determine whether the received event is relevant but if you *do* have the information up-front then could go with the separate subscription store.

In my FOSS ESB project (http://shuttle.codeplex.com/) a `ISubscriptionManager` implementation has to be provided to the ESB to determine the subscriber uris to send published messages to.  Although it *may* be overkill one could provide a custom implementation that contains some logic to perform the filtering; otherwise the separate subscription store.